# Configure exim4 to use Microsoft Exchange as smarthost

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, email-server, exim, gnutls

My company has set recently set up an Active Directory driven Microsoft Exchange environment to consolidate outgoing mails. We do have a set of staging servers which should now use our MSEXCHG as smarthost for outgoing mail.

These servers are located in the DMZ, which is why the upvoted solution in [Authenticating to Exchange 2010 smarthost?](https://serverfault.com/questions/399486/authenticating-to-exchange-2010-smarthost) is not an alternative, as we cannot allow a server in the DMZ to just send mails willy-nilly via our Exchange server.

Things we have done in MSEXCHG:

- Add a user (stagingserver@contoso.com)

Things we have done in `exim4 (8)`:

- Using `update-exim4.conf (8)` (c.f. `exim4_files (5)`) we configured exim to use `exchange.contoso.com:587` as a smarthost.
- In passwd.client (`exim4_files (5)`) I have added the following line: `exchange.contoso.com:stagingserver@activedirectory.contoso.com:secret123`)

After starting exim with the configuration described above, I get the following two TLS errors in *mainlog*:

- `TLS error on connection to ex.contoso.com [192.168.1.8] (recv): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.`
- `TLS error on connection to ex.contoso.com [192.168.1.8] (send): The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.`

Our MSEXCHG then refuses to send the mail and the following (ultimate) log entry shows up:

`** kiewiet@contoso.com R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost: SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<root@contoso-stage.com> SIZE=1538: host ex.contoso.com [192.168.1.8]: 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated`

Further things I have tried:

- Put `MAIN_TLS_ENABLE = 1` into `exim4.conf.localmacros` (http://blog.xig.ch/Exim-Smarthost-mit-Authentifizierung-%FCber-STARTTLS_127.html)
- Steps described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/167043/how-do-i-configure-exim4-to-send-mail-through-a-password-protected-ssl-smtp-mail

So, obligatory question: How can we get exim to use our MSEXCHG environment as smarthost?

Comment: Have you installed OpenSSL and tried the steps here: https://www.howtoforge.com/exim-authenticated-smarthost
esp.: AUTH_CLIENT_ALLOW_NOTLS_PASSWORDS = 1 ?

Comment: Have you tried testing the TLS connection by hand? `echo quit | openssl s_client -connect ex.contoso.com:587 -starttls smtp -crlf` or for `gnutls` ... `gnutls-cli --port 587 --starttls --verbose ex.contoso.com`

Comment: Yes, manual connection testing was successful. Sorry I forgot to mention that in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our problem was rather specific to our setup. We have more than one Exchange Server running in parallel with a load balancer acting as AP. The LB was malconfigured which caused it to neglect to offer any authentication method bar `NTLM` and `GSSAPI` even after successful `STARTTLS` handshake.

In-depth testing via `swaks` [jetmore.org](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) (can highly recommend this tool) revealed this.

Answer (score 1):

Does your organisation operate its own certificate authority for internal servers? Perhaps you need to add the CA certificates for the Exchange server into the certificate trust store for Exim? A lot of products don't report this error very well (I don't know if Exim does or not).

Wireshark (capture first on the server with `tcpdump -p -s0 -w /tmp/foo.pcap` then copy to a local workstation with Wireshark) should be able to show the server certificate send from Exchange, and if the client hangs up after that, then a missing CA certificate is a common cause.

Comment: Certificate validation is successful; tcpdump also shows that the STARTTLS handshake is seemingly successful; the three errors in the original question remained unchanged

Answer (score -2):

Problem is due to TLS certificates. Procedure to solve:

## Install openssl (if missing)

sudo apt-get install openssl

## Generate self certificates

sudo /usr/share/doc/exim4-base/examples/exim-gencert

## Add TLS to Main SMTP

sudo nano /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros

## or choose your default .conf file

main_tls_enable='1'